# Let x be a real number. Which of the following functions are right continuous distribution functions (with justification)?

Tags: statistics, functions, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, continuity

What would be a correct version, so that it is a right continuous distribution function?

$$F(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 2 \\
      0.5 & 2 < x < 3 \\
      1 & x \geq 3 
   \end{cases}
$$

$$G(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 2 \\
      0.25 & 2 < x \leq 3 \\
      1 & x > 3 
   \end{cases}
$$

---

According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Directional_and_semi-continuity

A right continuous function is simply a function that is continuous at a specific point when coming from the right, but is not necessarily continuous coming from the left

It seems to me that both functions are not right continuous. For $F(x)$, while it is right continuous between $1$ and $0.5$, it is not right continuous between $0.5$ and $0$. For $G(x)$, it is left continuous between $0$ and $0.25$, and also left continuous between $0.25$ and $1$, but it is not right continuous anywhere

To be right continuous, $F(x)$ would need to have $2 \leq x < 3$, and $G(x)$ would need to have $x \geq 3$ and $2 \leq x < 3$

We have no solutions to this exercise, could you give me your feedback ? Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-continuity at $x$ means that $F(x+)=F(x)$. (Here, $F(x+):=\lim_{t\to x, t>x}F(t)$.)

Compare $F(2+)$ to $F(2)$.
Likewise, compare $F(3+)$ to $F(3)$.

Do the same for $G$.

Comment: $F(3+) = F(3) = 1, F(2+) = 0.5 \neq F(2) = 0$, and $ G(3+) = 1 \neq 0.25 = G(3), G(2+) = 0.25 \neq G(2) = 0$ So only $F(3+) = F(3) = 1$ is right continuous, is this what you mean ?

Comment: So one can say that $F$ is r.c. at $3$, but $F$ is not r.c.  at $2$.  Because the right continuity fails (at $3$) one cannot say that $F$ is right continuous.

Could you modify $F$ slightly to make it right continuous? (Thereby a distribution function.)

Comment: You mean F fails at 2, not 3 ? Yes, F could be modified slightly to make it right continuous, by doing $F(x) = 0  $, $ x < 2$ and $F(x) = 0.5  $, $ 2 \leq x < 3$